# website scroll between pages

Tags: jquery, scroll, html

how can I build a website that scrolls between pages when a link is clicked?

eg, http://www.nofrks.com/

I found a jquery plugin called serial scroll http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/

can this be used to scroll between webpages?

Comment: At the nofrks page, in your browser, zoom out as much as possible.  You'll see that everything is in a single page and not multiple pages.  The position of the content is being moved inand out of view.

Answer (score 0):

the site you linked to only uses a single page, so unfortunately its not possible, due to page loading athough im sure with some thought you could make it "look" similar using some mad jquery skillz!